# bootstrap 3 shop layout with side thumbnails

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, thumbnails

I'm trying a web shop layout consisting in three columns:

| thumb | main image | description |

the thumbs column, contains three images that should be resized exactly to match the main image height. I'm using the *img-responsive* class but there are some minimal pixel differences when I display this layout on different sizes.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3" id="prodThumbs">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/170x255" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/170x255" class="img-responsive">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/170x255" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/534x800" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Price: 40,- €</h3>
            <button type="button" class="btn-default">add to cart</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is example http://jsfiddle.net/F6vtb/embedded/result/

Is there a better way to achieve this in bootstrap, so the images are perfectly aligned?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would just be to use a `table` instead of trying to use grid-columns. Grid-columns can be a pain to keep the same height.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/QpvE3/1/)